# 'The user must supply a JDBC connection' on weblogic restart

Tags: java, jdbc, initialization, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 11.
After initial deployment of all JMS configurations, JDBC configuration (from XADS-jdbc.xml) and ears everything works properly.

But after weblogic restart application fails to initialize with error

```
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
 at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:349)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)...
```

According to log JDBC and EAR start their initialization simultaniously. So when EAR tries to validate DB scheme JDBC configuration initialization is not completed yet.

What could fix such situation?
Are there any weblogic configurations using which deployment items initialization could be ordered?

Thanks in Advance.

#### persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="TestDSPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testN/test/TestXADS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>  -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="hibernate.test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" /> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Added persistence.xml content.

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Is your DataSource setup as a system module aka from Admin Console wizard and visible in config/jdbc/ or is it packaged in an application module (EAR) ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating the JDBC connections through admin console? If not, please try creating the data source through admin console. Once done, open your config.xml, you should see something like below:

```
      <jdbc-system-resource>
        <name>TestXADS</name>
        <target>AdminServer</target>
        <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/TestXADS-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
      </jdbc-system-resource>
```

Please Note: The outer node should be  **<jdbc-system-resource >**

Answer (score 0):

I would double check WebLogic is deploying resources in the default order as stated in [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13702/managing.htm#i1011243).